# Modify in place All column on a csv file except the Header

Tags: linux, awk

I have a csv file like this:

```
   Id EMAIL Service Number
    1 Test@email.com http 345 
    2 This.isATest@tmail.com dns 4 
    3 ConTact.Help@gmail.com ftp 4568
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
   Id EMAIL Service Number
    1 test@email.com http 345 
    2 this.isatest@tmail.com dns 4 
    3 contact.help@Gmail.com ftp 4568
```

I want to change the second field into lower-case and only the second field.

At the moment i managed to do it with awk, but it modify the second field of the first line too by lowering it to email ( i want the EMAIL to stay uppercase in this case but lower all the column )

```
awk '$2 = tolower($2)' test.csv >  tmp & mv tmp test.csv
```

Output:

```
   Id email Service Number
    1 test@email.com http 345 
    2 this.isatest@tmail.com dns 4 
    3 contact.help@Gmail.com ftp 4568
```

Question 2:

Is there a way after that to trigger the Field

> EMAIL
>   instead of doing $2 ?

edit to clear things:

In the case which the Field EMAIL ( and all the values in this column ) are not in the second field but in n-field, is there a way to trigger this field directly by searching the *EMAIL* and lower case the column ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your attempts, but your question specially 2nd part is not clear, please do add more details in your question for what you are trying to achieve and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thank you for you reply, i did an edit, hope things are clearer now

Comment: How come you invoke `toupper` instead of `tolower` to make the strings lowercase?

Comment: @Quasímodo My bad, i just edited the question. Using the NR doesn't work in my example and return me a csv file empty ( 0 oct )

Answer (score 1):

Possible to use `awk` NR to select only records 2 and above

Side note: the file is not "CSV", on surface, From the sample data (and the awk script), it is space separated or tab separated

The script is written for verbosity. Could be made more compact, if needed.

```
# Single line
awk 'NR > 1 { $2 = tolower($2) } { print }' < input-file-name > tmp && mv tmp input-file-name

# Multi-line
awk '
# Replace $2 on line 2+ with the lowercae
NR > 1 { $2 = tolower($2) }
# Print all lines
{ print }
' < input-file-name
```

Comment: Don't know why but by doing NR > 1 { $2 = tolower($2)  the file become null ( 0 octet )

Comment: The file indeed is csv but, i could not upload a csv in the question ?

Comment: @StillLearningHowtodoit Have a look at [how do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [edit] your question to include the csv file as it really is.

Comment: @dash-o I just modify the question, maybe i asked it in the wrong way, my code is working, i'm able to modify in place what i wanted but, couldn't ignore the header(first line )

Comment: I've modified the single line response to include the "in-place" editing. I'm still confused about the CSV/TSV. The sample data does not have commas